# How to run stored procedure in another database on the same server using a different login?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, authentication

I have 2 databases (**A** and **B**) on the same server. Database A has user **ua** defined, and database B has user **ub** defined.

I have a stored procedure in **A**, running as **ua**, that needs to run a stored procedure in **B**, running as **ub** (this is the only user that has access).

Until now, **A** and **B** were located on different servers, so I used linked server to switch login.
But now, when running the stored procedure in **A**, I get the following error: *"Transaction context in use by another session"*.

I understood from googling for this error that this is by design, based on Microsoft's [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188716.aspx) - it mentions that loopback linked servers cannot be used in a distributed transaction.

Are there any other ways to make the stored procedure in **A**, running as **ua**, to run the stored procedure in **B** as **ub**, if both databases are located on the same server?

Thanks a lot!
Alex

Comment: which database? Sounds like SQL Server...

Comment: Is it only this context that the proc should be executed as ub? The [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) can help if that's the case

Comment: @kevinsky it is SQL Server, sorry for not noting that...

Comment: @billinkc, if I understand your question correctly - the proc which is currently running under user "ua" can also run under user "ub".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ua` is associated with the login `la` and `ub` is associated with `lb`.

To make this work you could grant impersonation of `lb` to `la`. Then you can create a wrapper of b.dbo.someproc in a like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.b_someproc
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE AS LOGIN='lb';
  EXEC b.dbo.someproc;
  REVERT;
END;
```

However, impersonation is a very broad permission that you probably do not want to grant. To get around it you can either add user `ub` to database a or user `ua` to database b.

If you add `ub` to a you can write a wrapper like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.b_someproc
WITH EXECUTE AS 'ub'
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC b.dbo.someproc;
END;
```

By far the easiest way however is to ad `ua` to b and just allow it to call the procedure directly.

Comment: I don't have control over B database permissions, so I will probably have to go with adding `ub` to database A. One question regarding the latter code example - did you mean to refer to dbo.a_someproc instead of dbo.b_someproc?

`CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.a_someproc
WITH EXECUTE AS 'ub'
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC b.dbo.someproc;
END;`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: in both cases the procedure `dbo.b_someproc` lives in database `a` and is a pass-through wrapper to call `b.dbo.someproc`.